Unable to start R script from crontab - Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I tried to start R script from crontab on ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS but script didnt start
my code (edited by nano crontab -e)
gives
50 9 * * * Rscript 1.r

crontab edited without nano crontab -e
gives
no crontab for root


crontab -l

also gives no crontab for root
How can I solve this?

I don't think that it is how you are supposed to use crontab.  I am a begginer-intermediate on Linux, but it looks that nano crontab -e is creatint a [text] file called crontab, with the -e option of nano (" -e, --emptyline Do  not  use  the  line below the title bar, leaving it entirely blank.").
Modify you cronjobs with crontab -e like in this tutorial : https://linuxhandbook.com/crontab/  . Also, make sure to type your script right, 1.r  is not the same as 1.R.
You might want to check if you have "execute" permission on that file, but I am not so sure if it is required.
